# Number of primitive polynomial with limited coefficients

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

We cal a polynomial $f=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n\in\mathbb Z[x]$ primitive iff the greatest common divisor of  $a_0, a_1,\ldots, a_n$ is 1.

Let $d$ and $m$ be positive integrs and let $$T_m^d=\{f=a_0+a_1x+\ldots+a_dx^d\in\mathbb Z[x]\;:\; f\;  \text{ is primitive and } |a_i|<m\}.$$
How many elements have the set $T_m^d$?

Answer (score 2):

We fix an element $d$, The number of elements such that of $T_{m+1}^d$ is exactly the number of tuples such that: $$\gcd(a_0,\cdots,a_d)=1\,\, \text{ and }|a_i|\leq m$$

Let denote this number by $S_d(m)$ it's clear that:
$$m^d=\sum_{i=1}^{m}S_d\left({\left\lfloor \frac{m}{i} \right\rfloor}\right)$$

This can be proven by partitioning the set of all possible tuples $[1,m]^d$ on subsets $D_i$ for which $\gcd(a_1,\cdots,a_d)=i$. Concerning the question there  is no closed formula for $S_d(m)$ but these numbers was studied, one classic exercise as an application of series and Riemann sums is proving that:
$$S_2(m)\sim \frac{6m^2}{\pi^2} $$

and there is a generalization of this result:
$$S_d(m)\sim \frac{m^d}{\zeta(d)} $$